# Setting PersistenceContext to EXTENDED in XML Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.1 and Spring 4.1.6 and I would like to set the PersistenceContext to extended mode by using Spring XML configuration and not annotations.

It seems this is at least not well documented.

With annotation this is really simple but I can't figure it out in xml :

```java
@PersistenceContext(unitName="PU", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I'm really interested in knowing if someone has already done this or can argue this  is possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: And why should it be any different with Spring... You use exactly the same, you can only specify this with annotations as you need to know that where you use at that specific location.

Comment: I've got a whole old application that is configured via several Spring xml files. The entity manager factory, the datasource, the dao. So it would be fine to only have to add a line of xml in a xml file instead of using an annotation. Furthermore, the entity manager is injected via a shared entity bean in xml.

Comment: Obtaining the `EntityManager` is either a manual creation using `EntityManagerFactory` or by using annotations to inject it. There is no other way (even the `SharedEntityManagerBean` needs that as it is only a factory for an `EntityManager`). So no you cannot globally configure this as, mentioned earlier, you specify the `type` on the injection/creation point in your code.